# cakephp common action for admin and member

Tags: cakephp

For my project I have three types of users. Admins, members and Others.
There are certain functions that both admin and members could perform.

I know how to do routing and check for admin, and calling admin methods. But am not sure how to share a function between user types.

Any hint?

Best,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do it using Auth component.
Uncomment  `Routing.prefixes = array('admin', 'manager');` in your app/Config/core.php file.

Setup an Auth component with the help of [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).
Now if your controller's method is common with two user roles 'admin' and 'manager', then it is simple to define a method for any role and invoke it in another method.

Lets say in your UsersController.php

```
public function admin_list()
{
  /*.... define here ..... */
}
public function manager_list()
{
    $this->admin_list();
}
```

This technique will also help you to manage if you want to show some other things with user list for the manager user role.

Comment: You can also use `setAction()` to actually use that action and render its view. http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction

Comment: I had uncommented the line in core.php, but wondering if when manager_list() is called won't cakephp ask for the view of manager_list?

Answer (score 0):

Use isAuthorized() from Auth component. Let's say that your users is in table users.
In your AppController.php put:

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
     return true;
}
```

In your UsersController, lets say that you want method1 and method2 to be visible only for admins and members, not for others.

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
     if(in_array($this->action, array('method1', 'method2'))){
          if($user['role'] != 'admin' || $user['role'] != 'user'){
               return false;
          }
     }
     return true;
}
```

And, of course, include your AuthComponent in AppController:

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Auth');
```

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: ahh...so we can override the isAuthorized in the required controller? Didn't know that, let me try. Seems to be cleaner. Thx

Comment: nope...its still expecting me to name the action as admin_addEdit(), instead of just addEdit(). I wanted to keep the action name as just addEdit(), so that this common action be access by both 'admin' and 'creator' :-(